# Extract multiple lines from block of text EXCEL

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

```
<div>
            <div class="materials">
              <h6>Heading 1</h6>
              <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>   
                <li>Item 2</li>    
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="features">
              <h6>Heading 2</h6>
              <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>  
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
<Rest of code>
```

I'm looking to extract the list after `<h6>heading 2</h6>` to the `</ul>` but not the first unordered list eg. below.

```
<ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>  
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                  </ul>
```

I've been attempting this using MID and SEARCH and LEN but due to the new lines and each target cell having a different length list I'm running into issues.
Would anyone have suggestions on how to tackle this one?

Comment: how does `MID and SEARCH and LEN` used to extract single line? Mind Sharing how the excel table look like (after pasting it inside excel)? (Hint : edit post and look for how to insert a table. the menu should be somewhere at the right side..)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, honestly it's not worth adding the table won't allow me with the HTML either. 

But it's three columns:
ID | Code | Result
1  | Code in body | My forumla

Answer (score 0):

Assumne A1 contains

```
<li>Item 1</li>
```

The solution should be :

```
=MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-LEN("<li></li>"))
```

Idea : total len = len `<li>` + len `</li>`+ len `Item 1`. use the info to 'guide' `MID()` function.

Please share if it works/not.